# I am trying to get all folders on my machine but it only gives relative path I want full path

Tags: python, directory, operating-system, drive

*No one come in here and say use os.path.abspath() I tried, it literally doesn't do what I want it just gives everything the drive of the current directory which isn't what I want I want to have the real drive.

I am getting the full path without the drive

example:

```bash
\\FileHistory\\fun64\\RAMPAGE\\Data\\$OF\\6413
```

Its not specifying the drive.

Code:

```py
import os

root_dir = '\\'

folders = []

for path, dirs, files in os.walk(root_dir):
    for dir in dirs:
        full_path = os.path.join(path, dir)
        folders.append(full_path)

print(folders)
```

I want to Specify what drive the folder is on at the start

Comment: No one say use os.path.abspath() test it yourself go to a drive and get the relative path for a folder and try it, it will give the drive of the current directory

Answer (score 0):

```py
import os
import win32api

folders = []

for drive in win32api.GetLogicalDriveStrings().split('\000')[:-1]:
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(drive):
        for dir in dirs:
            full_path = os.path.join(path, dir)
            folders.append(full_path)
print(folders)
```

Comment: Your question did not ask for how to iterate over all available drives.